# Treatment of sbottoms in prospino

Tags: particle-physics, supersymmetry

Could someone please explain the details of the following "propaganda plot" from the [prospino website](http://www.thphys.uni-heidelberg.de/~plehn/prospino/)?

There is one curve for stop pair production $\tilde t \bar {\tilde t}$, and one for general squark pair production $\tilde q \bar {\tilde q}$. Is the pair production of sbottoms lumped together with the other squarks, or is it missing here? If it is included in the $\tilde q \bar {\tilde q}$ curve, are the cross sections for the non-stop squarks nearly identical, or is this just the inclusive cross section for the production of any heavy squark pair? And finally what model/constraints are assumed in this plot?

[image: Prospino propaganda plot for LHC]